# How to remove all occurrences of an element from NumPy array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

The title is pretty self-explanatory: I have an numpy array like (let's say ints)
`[ 1 2 10 2 12 2 ]` and I would like to remove all occurrences of `2`, so that the resulting array is `[ 1 10 12 ]`. Preferably I would like to do this as fastest as possible, because I am using relatively large arrays.

NumPy has a function called `numpy.delete()` but it takes the indexes as an argument, which I do not have.

Edit: The question is indeed different from [Deleting certain elements from numpy array using conditional checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917703/deleting-certain-elements-from-numpy-array-using-conditional-checks), which is I guess a more "general" case. However, the idea of removing occurrences from an array is fundamental enough to merit its own explicit question, so I am keeping the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use indexing:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 10, 2, 12, 2])
print(arr[arr != 2])
# [ 1 10 12]
```

Timing is pretty good:

```
from timeit import Timer

arr = np.array(range(5000))
print(min(Timer(lambda: arr[arr != 4999]).repeat(500, 500)))
# 0.004942436999999522
```

Comment: @Georgy It's not a duplicate. OP is using a numpy array

Comment: Did you open the link?

Comment: @Georgy I opened the link in your comment to the question. Only the 10th answer in your duplicated question refer to numpy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I am also confused about the syntax, could you perhaps clarify on that ? Are we using masks, or filtering, or mapping ...

Comment: @mlg556 It's masking, try to `print(arr == 2)` and see what it returns.

Answer (score 3):

you can use another numpy function.It is numpy.setdiff1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique=False).
This function Finds the set difference of two arrays.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 10, 2,12, 2])
b = np.array([2])
c = np.setdiff1d(a,b,True)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. I suggest you use a mask:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([ 1, 2 ,10, 2, 12, 2 ])
a[~np.isin(a, 2)]
>> array([ 1, 10, 12])
```

`np.isin` is convenient because you can apply the filter to multiple elements at once if you need to:

```
a[~np.isin(a, (1,2))]
>>  array([ 10, 12])
```

Also note that `a[mask]` is a slice of the original array. This is memory efficient; but if you need to create a new array with your filtered values and leave the original ones untouched, use `.copy`, e.g.:

```
b = a[~np.isin(a, (1,2))].copy()
```